# Indexing map type structure in SOLR

Tags: solr

Hi I need to do the following

I have to provide a faceted search  by skills , Ex: Java, C++, etc...

When user click Java , it should show years of experience, so the user can query for people who has experience for 3 years in Java, 1 years in C++.

I'm wondering how can I can index this in SOLR , to implement the requirement.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can try the following :-

1. Store the Skills in a separate multivalued field to facet upon
2. Create Dynamic fields for skills so that the name of the field in the skill and the value it holds is the years of experience
3. If you filter on any fields e.g. Java, use the facet range query to return yrs of experience as a faceted range

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I also thought that way, I'm going to use the skills also as a facet.

Comment: also use the facet range for the other requirements you have